# Логика работы с Canvas в Angular. Архитектура приложения

Tags: angular2, canvas, архитектура, angular5

Есть задача реализовать график курса валюты в Angular через Canvas. Условие задачи: нельзя использовать библиотеки работы с Canvas. Из красивостей: за курсором при перемещении должна следовать вертикальная черта вдоль графика и подсвечивать текущую точку на кривой. Естественно, рядом с точкой должно быть численное значение курса, дата и разница с предыдущим днём. Это моё первое приложение на Angular и TypeScript.

Сделал загрузку данных через сервис, с ожиданием данных через `Observable`. Сделал два класса. Экземпляры класса `CanvasSettings` будут содержать инфу о размере, отступах и всего, что касается слоёв `Canvas`. Их будет 2, один поверх другого. Первый будет содержать графику, которую не надо перерисовывать, второй будет специализироваться именно на динамической графике.

Второй класс, `DatePoints`, содержит подробную инфу о курсах, координаты точек, разница со вчерашним днём и простейшие функции расчёта некоторых данных.

Взаимодействие классов происходит в `app.component.ts`. В компоненте происходит парсинг инфы из источника, проверка точек на правильность, сортировка по порядку и наполнение экземпляра `DatePoints`, расчёт начального и конечного значений по шкале Y, чтобы кривая курса умещалась с небольшим отступом от низа и от верха, расчёт промежутков под месяцы и дни в каждом месяце по шкале X, а также равномерное рассредоточение дней в каждом месяце (не все дни торговые и число торговых дней в каждом месяце разное).

Все вопросы по архитектуре. Данную информацию не получилось нагуглить ни в ru, ни в en сегментах Сети.

**Собственно вопросы.**

1. Самый главный вопрос: в каком месте компонента следует
   размещать вызов функций отрисовки статичного слоя Canvas, а в каком
   динамического?
2. Как передавать
   координаты положения мыши над динамическим слоем? `@HostListener('document:mousemove', ['$event'])`? Если да, то как вместо `document:mousemove` указать область прослушивания события `мойCanvasЭлемент:mousemove`?
3. Как запускать
   функцию перерисовки динамического слоя при помощи Angular с заданным
   интервалом? Если нужно писать свою функцию дросселирования (aka *тормозилка*), типа `throttle` в lowdash, так и скажите, без подробностей, а вот если это не *Angular way*, то поясните, пожалуйста или скажите, что гуглить.

**Пример кода `app.component.ts`**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CanvasSettings } from './canvas-settings';
import { Rate } from './rate';
import { RateService } from './rates.service';
import { DatePoints, Year, Month, Day } from './dates';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
    providers: [RateService]
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    title = 'Exchange Rates via Canvas';
    bgrdCanvas = new CanvasSettings("bgrdCanvas");          // статический слой
    interactiveCanvas = new CanvasSettings("iaCanvas");     // динамический слой
    rates: Rate[];
    dateArray: DatePoints;

    constructor(private _rateService: RateService){

    }

    ngOnInit() {

        this.getRates();        // получаем массив котировок в this.rates
        this.parseDataArray();  // перебиваем значения в объект this.dateArray, точки, не соответсвующие формату данных, выбрасываем
        this.organizeArray();   // сортируем, чтобы даты в массивах this.dateArray шли по порядку друг за другом
        this.setDiffs();        // высчитываем diffы между каждой парой точек в this.dateArray
        this.calculateCoords(); // вычисляем координаты каждой точки на Canvas слое, учитывая отступы и равномерную разбивку дней внутри каждого месяца
        this.setAxisExtremums();

        }

    getRates():void {
        this._rateService.getRates()
            .subscribe(rates => this.rates = rates);

    }

    parseDateFromRate(rate: Rate): Array<number> {

        //...

    }
    parseDataArray():void {

        //...

    }
    organizeArray():void {

        //...

    }
    setDiffs():void {

        //...

    }
    calculateCoords():void {

        //...

    }
    setAxisExtremums():void {

        //...

    }
    drawStaticCanvas():void { // где вызывать?

        let canvas = document.getElementById(this.bgrdCanvas.idSelector);
        console.log(canvas);
        let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    }
    drawDynamicCanvas():void { // где вызывать? Есть ли throttle?

        //...

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Вызов функции отрисовки динмаческого Canvas слоя происходит в HTML-коде компонента, точнее вызов не самой функции отрисовки, а функции-обёртки, которая контролирует частоту вызова. Функция вызывается в событии `onmousemove` внутри тега: `(mousemove)="redrawWrapper($event)"`. Ниже весь код.

**app.component.html** ():

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{ title }}!
  </h1>
  <img width="300" alt="Angular Logo" src="...">
</div>

<div class="canvasOuter">

    <!-- Это статический слой -->
    <canvas id="{{bgrdCanvas.idSelector}}" width="{{bgrdCanvas.width}}"
    height="{{bgrdCanvas.height}}"></canvas>

    <!-- Это динамически перерисовываемый слой -->
    <canvas id="{{dynCanvas.idSelector}}" width="{{dynCanvas.width}}"
    height="{{dynCanvas.height}}"
    (mousemove)="redrawWrapper($event)"></canvas>

    <div class="canv-helper" #helper>
        <span class="canv-helper__date"></span>
        <span class="canv-helper__data helper-data">
            <span class="helper-data__cost"></span>
            <span class="helper-data__diff"></span>
        </span>
    </div>

</div>

<footer></footer>
```

2. Проброс координат положения мыши НАД элементом в `AppComponent` осуществляем следующим образом. Подчёркиваю слово **над**, поскольку координаты над другими элементами не будут регистрироваться. Само событие и координаты мыши нам даёт код `(mousemove)="redrawWrapper($event)"`, из предыдущего вопроса.

В листинге ниже привожу сильно урезанный код, чтобы продемонстрировать только проброс координат.

**app.component.ts**:

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, ElementRef, ViewChild, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
import { CanvasSettings } from './canvas-settings';
import { Rate } from './rate';
import { RateService } from './rates.service';
import { DatePoints, Year, Month, Day, Monthes, ofMonth } from './dates';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
    providers: [RateService]
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

    event: MouseEvent; // создаём свойство внутри компонента
    clientX: number = 0;
    clientY: number = 0;

    onEvent(event: MouseEvent): void {

        this.event = event; // и записываем в него событие

    }

    redrawWrapper(event: MouseEvent) { // запускает redraw через дроссель,
    //но об этом потом

        let that = this;
        let event = that.event; // вот тут само таинство, делаем переменную event ссылкой на объект события
        let clientX: number = event.clientX; // и перебиваем координаты
        let clientY: number = event.clientY;

    }

}
```

3. К сожалению, моя функция-дроссель делает задержку лишь для одного из методов компонента (методом называют функцию объекта). Это не универсальное решение, но оно демонстрирует, как следует собирать свою *тормозилку*.

   ```
   import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, ElementRef, ViewChild, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
   import { CanvasSettings } from './canvas-settings';
   import { Rate } from './rate';
   import { RateService } from './rates.service';
   import { DatePoints, Year, Month, Day, Monthes, ofMonth } from './dates';

   @Component({
       selector: 'app-root',
       templateUrl: './app.component.html',
       styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
       providers: [RateService]
   })

   export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

       @ViewChild("helper") helper: ElementRef;

       event: MouseEvent;
       //...
       isThrottled: boolean = false; // текущий статус, тикает сейчас таймер или нет

       onEvent(event: MouseEvent): void {

           this.event = event;

       }

   redrawWrapper(event: MouseEvent) { // функция-дроссель для метода redraw

       this.event = event;
       let that = this;
       let savedThis: any;

       function wrapper() {

           if (that.isThrottled) { // если запущен, сохраняем контекст запуска, т.е. this.
               savedThis = that;   // Записываем контекст последнего вызова.
                                   // Это больше актуально, когда дросселировать
                                   // предполагается разные функции, а не одну, как у меня.
                                   // В моём случае эта переменная является индикатором,
                                   // контролирующим, был ли вызов функции после её
                                   // последнего исполнения. Это нужно, чтобы вызвать
                                   // функцию ещё раз, если вызов был. Без этого
                                   // анимация не проследует за курсором,
                                   // т.к. во время действия таймера курсор сдвинулся
                                   // ещё немного.
               return;
           }

           // запускаем функцию. that - это контекст, т.е. объект,
           // который будет подразумеваться под this,
           // that.event - это свойство текущего компонента
           that.redraw.call(that, that.event);

           that.isThrottled = true;

           setTimeout(function() {

               that.isThrottled = false;

               if (savedThis) {

                   // обратите внимание, вызываем не redraw(), а wrapper()
                   wrapper.apply(savedThis);
                   savedThis = null;

               }

           }, 40); // количество миллисекунд, через которое вызываем функцию

       }

       return wrapper();

   }

   redraw(event: MouseEvent): void { // эта функция обеспечивает динамическую перерисовку Canvas

       //...

       this.redrawHelper(point, whichYear, whichMonth, currentDayIndex);

       //...

   }

   redrawHelper(point: Day, year: number, month: number, day: number):void {

       //...

       this.setHelperPosition(point);

   }

   setHelperPosition(point: Day):void {

       //...

   }

   constructor(private _rateService: RateService, private renderer: Renderer2){

   }

   //...
   ```

   }

Если вы это нагуглили, надеюсь мой код чем-то помог вам. Репозиторий проекта тут: https://bitbucket.org/frost7/exchange-rates